# How to hide a div by clicking in the button inside it

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide a `DIV` by clicking on a button inside it( without knowing the id and the class of the div).

is that possible using `JQuery` ?

Answer (score 6):

#### Description

You can do this using jQuery's `click()`, `.parent()` and `.hide()` method.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/TVJWD/)

#### Sample

```
<div><button>hide</button></div>
<div><button>hide</button></div>
<div><button>hide</button></div>
<div><button>hide</button></div>

$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/TVJWD/)
- [jQuery.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [jQuery.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [jQuery.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)